# Can't understand a line in a "Collective intelligence" program

Tags: python, debugging

I'm working through "[Programming collective intelligence](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529321)". In chapter 4, Toby Segaran builds an artificial neural network. The following function appears on page of the book:

```
def generatehiddennode(self,wordids,urls):
  if len(wordids)>3: return None
  # Check if we already created a node for this set of words
  sorted_words=[str(id) for id in wordids]
  sorted_words.sort()
  createkey='_'.join(sorted_words)
  res=self.con.execute(
  "select rowid from hiddennode where create_key='%s'" % createkey).fetchone()

  # If not, create it
  if res==None:
    cur=self.con.execute(
    "insert into hiddennode (create_key) values ('%s')" % createkey)
    hiddenid=cur.lastrowid
    # Put in some default weights
    for wordid in wordids:
      self.setstrength(wordid,hiddenid,0,1.0/len(wordids))
    for urlid in urls:
      self.setstrength(hiddenid,urlid,1,0.1)
    self.con.commit()
```

What I can't possibly understand is the reason of the first line in this function: 'if len(wordids>3): return None`. Is it a debug code that needs to be removed later?

P.S. this is not a homework

Comment: Impossible to tell, really, without knowing more about the rest of the program. If the program isn't intended to work with more than 3 `wordid`s, then this would seem fine (personally I'd probably raise an exception, but perhaps the return value gets checked elsewhere). If it's intended to work with any number, then it may be an error. Sample code in books often contains mistakes.

Comment: At first glance it looks like some form of primitive error check. It looks like the length of wordids is supposed to be 3 or less. If you supply the function with a wordids variable of greater length then the function will do nothing.

Comment: It's performing some input restriction, that the functino should only run on a maximimum of a triplet of "words". Presumably returning None is easier than doing an `assert` or `raise` in this case.

Comment: "The following function appears on page of the book:" You forgot the page number, which is 77 in the version in Safari Online (from the August 2007 print edition, I believe).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a published book, that's pretty terrible code!  (You can download all the examples for the book [from here](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596529321/PCI_Code.zip); the relevant file is `chapter4/nn.py`.)

- No docstring. What is this function supposed to do? From its name, we can guess that it's generating one of the nodes in the "hidden layer" of a neural network, but what role do the `wordids` and `urls` play?
- Database query uses string substitution and so is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (especially since this is something to do with web searching, so the `wordids` probably come from a user query and so may be untrusted—but then, maybe they are ids rather than words so it's OK in practice but still a very bad habit to get into).
- Not using the expressive power of the database: if all you want to do is to determine if a key exists in the database then you probably want to use a `SELECT EXISTS(...)` rather than asking the database to send you a bunch of records which you're then going to ignore.
- Function does nothing if there was already a record with `createkey`. No error. Is that correct? Who can say?
- The weighting for the words is scaled to the numbers of words, but the weighting for the urls is the constant `0.1` (perhaps there are always 10 URLs, but it would be better style to scale by `len(urls)` here).

I could go on and on, but I better not.

Anyway, to answer your question, it looks as though this function is adding a database entry for a node in the hidden layer of a [neural network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network). This neural network has, I think, words in the input layer, and URLs in the output layer. The idea of the application is to attempt to train a neural network to find good search results (URLs) based on the words in the query. See the function `trainquery`, which takes the arguments `(wordids, urlids, selectedurl)`. Presumably (since there's no docstring I have to guess) `wordids` were the words the user searched for, `urlids` are the URLs the search engine offered the user, and `selectedurl` is the one the user picked. The idea being to train the neural net to better predict which URLs users will pick, and so place those URLs higher in future search results.

So the mysterious line of code is preventing nodes being created in the hidden layer with links to more than three nodes in the input layer. In the context of the search application this makes sense: there's no point in training up the network on queries that are too specialized, because these queries won't recur often enough for the training to be worth it.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with your criticisms. Both the code and the explanation of the mathematics underlying the algorithms are sloppy in this book. As a suggestion, you should probably edit your answer to put your actual answer first, and criticisms after. Like a good newspaper article, the best answers have the pithy meat at the top, and fluff at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you.  I was beginning to think I was some kind of Python god, and the only one who realized the code in this book sucks.  Thanks for bringing me back to earth.  This book is an interesting introduction to machine learning, but the code made me want to cry.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should have posted a little more context for code. Here is the paragraph in *Programming Collective Intelligence* which immediately precedes that code:

> This function will create a new node
>   in the hidden layer every time it is
>   passed a combination of words that it
>   has never seen together before. The
>   function then creates default-weighted
>   links between the words and the hidden
>   node, and between the query node and
>   the URL results returned by this
>   query.

I realize it still doesn't help answer your question, but it would have helped Gareth Rees out with his answer by giving less guesswork. Gareth still got it correct, anyway, since he's clever. The intention is to restrict the number of word nodes a hidden node can be associated with, and the author chose the arbitrary number of 3.

Just to agree with Gareth, again, that paragraph should have totally been in the docstring, and the purpose of the line in question should have been in a comment above the line. I hope the next edition isn't so sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the above comments look at this simple script...

```
def doSomething(wordids):
  if len(wordids)>3: return None
  print("The rest of the function executes")


blah = [2,3,4];
doSomething(blah)

blah = [2,3,4,5];
doSomething(blah)
```

. . so if the length of wordids is longer than 3 then the function does nothing. It is common to check the inputs to functions but errors are normally handled using exceptions in more advanced cases.

Comment: I presume the OP knows *what* the line does, just not *why*.